# How to use googletrans's Translator on SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to translate couple of columns in cloud MySQL table using `googletrans`'s `Translator` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql:......")
Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = Session()
translator = Translator()
```

Here I read the MySQL table:

```
sql_stmt = "SELECT * FROM translate"
data = session.execute(sql_stmt)
```

And then here I try to translate it:

```
for to_translate in data:
    data.col1_Translated = translator.translate(to_translate.col1, dest = 'en')
    data.col2_Translated = translator.translate(to_translate.col2, dest = 'en')
```

But when I try to see if the translation took place using below code, I get no output.

```
for rows in data:
    print(rows.col1, rows.col1_Translated, rows.col2, rows.col2_Translated)
```

I am new to SQLALchemy and unable to find a solution. Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong and how to access the columns and apply the Translator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you want:

```
for to_translate in data:
    to_translate.col1_Translated = translator.translate(to_translate.col1, dest = 'en')
    # instead of:
    # data.col1_Translated = ...
    to_translate.col2_Translated = translator.translate(to_translate.col2, dest = 'en')
```

Right? You are assigning to **data**.col1_Translated so it gets overwritten each pass of the cycle.

If that's not the problem, try:

```
for to_translate in data:
    print(translator.translate(to_translate.col1, dest = 'en'))
    print(translator.translate(to_translate.col2, dest = 'en'))
```

just to see if anything got translated. If it is, what do you want to do with the translation?

Comment: Peter, how do I check if the translation took place in the object? When I try: `for cols in data:
    print(cols)` I don't see an output. Also, could you please let me know how to reflect the changes in the underlying table in the database

Comment: `for cols in data: print(cols)` ?!? But data is not cols but rows, right? You do not see any output? AFAIK some engines let you iterate only once. Why not run the query again?

Comment: As to writing the data to database, really you will be better off by looking at the sqlalchemy docs - expression language tutorial.